# GeForce GTX 550 ti and Linux?

Tags: 11.10, wubi

When I try to install any form of Linux, including Ubuntu, Kubuntu,and even *Mint* the installation gives me an error because if my PCI device which is my GPU. This error flashes over and over again, and then times out. I want to dual boot windows 7 and Ubuntu but Ubuntu simply fails to install.. whats wrong? I know the problem is because of my GPU because it will install with on-board graphics..

Comment: And what *error* does it give you?... FYI, when you say any form of Linux and then you Say Ubuntu, Kubuntu and Mint, your're basically using the same OS.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problems installing Mint 12, Oneric, Precise Beta and some others. I *think* the free Nouveaux Drivers don't support this board yet, so can't launch an x-server. I have posted a bug in the hope someone will pick it up and fix it.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/969121

I have been told that you can use Ubuntu Customisation Kit to respin Ubuntu to load the non-free proprietary drivers when your live system boots. However, I don't know that it would be an easy fix because it takes more space on the disk, which would mean you would have to do a USB mounted burn of the .iso, not to mention you would have to tell the installed version to load those drivers also. If I find a way to triage this, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Last week I spent 3 days trying to get a GeForce GTX 550 ti working in various flavors and versions of Ubuntu.

In the LTS version of Ubuntu - 10.04 - it is necessary to download and install the drivers (currently version 295.33) from the NVIDIA web site.  Without them Ubuntu runs in a basic VGA-type mode.

In Xubuntu 11.10 it will work and use the Ubuntu-provided driver at version 280.13 from the Ubuntu Software Center.

This seems to work well

Answer (score 1):

I am using a GeForce GTX 560 Ti in an ubuntu 10.10 and the NVIDA development drivers with no problems. Download the drivers from [here](http://www.geforce.com/drivers), and here you [have](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-install-nvidia-drivers-manually-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx.html) a tutorial of how to install them. It is quite easy and smooth.

They [claim](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-295.59-driver.html) to have full support for 550 ti cards in driver version 295.59, so that should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've had Gigabyte GTX 550 Ti some time ago and the same problem appeard. Basically to install Ubuntu with this card you must set up **nomodeset** in installation boot screen. To do this just press F6 when installation options(Try, Install etc.)shows and check nomodeset option - installation will go smoothly after this.
When the installation of OS is finished just install gpu driver from Additional Drivers menu and... that's it.